# SQL group sequence ids and count them (sqlServer)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

Easy question: Following single table with IDs

```
    IDS
    5
    6
    7
    8
    13
    14
```

What I want

```
    MinID   MaxID   Count
    5       8       4
    13      14      2
```

Any Idea? CTE are my pesonal preferences

Comment: There are'nt 4 `5`s in the table, how would you get that count? Do you involve another table you haven't mentioned?

Comment: how do you choose min, max or count? your expected result does not make sense

Comment: Oh... do you want to count IDs in a certain range?

Comment: The purpose of your question is not clear. Please try to explain your goal in more depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method uses `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
select min(id), max(id), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (id - seqnum)
order by min(id);
```

That is, if the difference between a sequence of numbers and `id` is constant when the `id` values are sequential.

Comment: So smooth and brilliant logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` find the grouping & do aggregation :

```
select min(ids) as minid, max(ids) as maxid, count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when ids - prev_ids = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by ids) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(ids) over (order by ids) as prev_ids
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to group by based on number of digit.

```
select len(id) ln , min(id) , max(id) , count (*) from tab1
group by len(id) ;
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/NGFP4026)

Answer (score 0):

This example uses variables for minimum and maximum id:

```sql
DECLARE @minID INTEGER,
        @maxID INTEGER;

SET @minID = 13;
SET @maxID = 14;

SELECT
    @maxID AS MaxID,
    @minID AS MinID,
    COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM
    #ids
WHERE
    id <= @maxID
    AND
    id >= @minID
```

and it outputs

```
MaxID   MinID   Count
14      13      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below query. It groups them together based on the range.

This will help even when your values are not sequential.

```
select min(id) as MinID, max(id) as MaxID, count(*) as cnt
from (select id,case when id between 1 and 9 then '1-9'
                     when id between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
                   --when id between 20 and 29 then '20-29' & so on
                end as Grp from your_table) g
group by Grp
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ec77d9259065ef22421230b86d1bb50)

*You can alter the case based on your logic for spiting the range values i.e.,`1-9` or `1-10`*